# Get warnings when programmatically parsing Dart file with analyzer_experimental

Tags: dart, analyzer

I am using [analyzer_experimental](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/tree/master/dart/pkg/analyzer_experimental) to parse a Dart file into a CompilationUnit:

```dart
import 'package:analyzer_experimental/analyzer.dart';

var unit;
try {
  unit = parseDartFile(path);
} on AnalyzerErrorGroup catch(e){
  print(e);
}
```

The above code will catch any parsing errors encountered.

I am also interested in seeing any warnings associated with the file (e.g. 'Undefined name "foo"'). I know that the experimental_analyzer library has the capability to generate these warnings when running from the command line but it does not seem to be possible to get the warnings programmatically, without directly referencing classes in the src folder (which seems like a bad idea).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried [AnalyzerImpl](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/pkg/analyzer_experimental/lib/src/analyzer_impl.dart) instead?

Comment: That's what I was referring to by "classes in the src folder". If there is no other option I can use it but it's not the best practice to dig into another library's src folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely this package was very incomplete at the time.

There's now an [analyzer package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) on pub and also a (work-in-progress) STDIN/STDOUT [Analyzer Service](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/analyzer-discuss) aimed to help making tooling support easier for IDE extension authors.